# Unable to deploy Azure Function with Premium Service Plan

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

When I try to create a FunctionApp Premium Plan using the following commands:

```
# Create a Resource Group
az group create \
    --name $rg_name \
    --location $az_loc

# Create a Function App Storage Account
az storage account create \
    --name $fa_storage_name \
    --resource-group $rg_name \
    --location $az_loc \
    --sku Standard_LRS

# Create a Premium plan
az functionapp plan create \
    --name $fap_name \
    --resource-group $rg_name \
    --location $az_loc \
    --sku P2v2
```

I receive an error:

> The requested app service plan cannot be created in the current
> resource group because it is hosting Linux apps. Please choose a
> different resource group or create a new one.

I also tried the sku `EP2` with same result. The SKU's are really hard to find in the docs(!). Does anyone know which sku's work with Linux Azure Functions and what I might be missing here?

Comment: This is function plan conflict. Please create it in a new resourse group or create it in a  resourse group with no conflict plan..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what ended up working for me. Note the `--is-linux true` flag in `az functionapp plan create` and the `--plan` flag in `az functionapp create`:

```
# Create a Premium plan
az functionapp plan create \
  --name $fap_name \
  --is-linux true \
  --resource-group $rg_name \
  --location $az_loc \
  --sku EP2

# Create Function App (container for Azure Function)
#--consumption-plan-location $az_loc \
az functionapp create \
  --name $fa_name \
  --resource-group $rg_name \
  --storage-account $fa_storage_name \
  --plan $fap_name \
  --os-type Linux \
  --runtime python \
  --runtime-version 3.7 \
  --subscription $az_sub \
  --functions-version 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is common error.

The solution is to create a new Resourse Group and put the function app in.

The problem comes from the conflict between azure function plan based on windows and based on linux.

Create a new Resource group is the only way, and notice to separate function based on linux and windows in your development.

Comment: This is being created as part of a script. A new resource group is created, storage account, function app plan (SKU: P2v2), function app, and other resources. The error pops up as part of the script running.

Answer (score -1):

There is a current limitation where Windows and Linux apps cannot exist in the same resource group.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro#limitations

Therefore, it was failing when deploying a Windows resource and worked when --is-linux was set to true

Comment: Hm. I've only deployed Python Function Apps. They are all Linux-based. (At this time) Windows Apps do not handle Python runtimes.

Comment: This is no longer true, per the link in your answer, as of Jan 2021.